# Why can`t see apk files?

Tags: android, xml, macos, android-manifest, apk

I can open apk, but can`t see files . Why ?
Normally, would be seen  xml  files,  manifest  file  and  so  on  ,  but  all  can  i  see  are question marks  and  bars.
  Text Wrangler is code editor used for mac.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably for the best. Otherwise someone simply recompile your source code and generate their own app off the back of your hard work.

Answer (score 2):

Although Java is normally an interpreted language, the architecture of android is set up to compile the code you write when generating the .apk. Basically, the .apk does not contain your source code, only your compiled code.

Comment: What should i do? This apk is the one i have to work with. I need it to upgrade to last version of android my app. I did not make the project itself, i have only this apk to work with.

Comment: Should apk contain both source code and compiled code or only source code ? I am begineer in making android apps

Comment: Java is NOT interpreted, it is always compiled.